Is there a way to automate the setup of a server made by a bot?
I have been trying to create a bot that can clone a discord server.
The clone would include the server's name, server image/banner, categories, channels (including settings), roles, up to 10 past messages per channel with timestamp and user credit, and re-invite bots.
I can already have the bot create a discord server and do various things with it, such as adding channels, roles, etc. Even as much as inviting users and transferring ownership but even with the level of server owner, I still can't figure out how or if I can have it invite other bots.
what I am asking here is if it's possible to re-add the bots automatically or if the most I can do is sent the appropriate link for each bot like I've done already?

Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask].

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Bots can't add other bots to a server. The best you can do is send links to add each bot, maybe with the same permissions they had in the cloned server.
